# How to get the number of weeks in a particular year? Also how to get the current year using zend?

Tags: zend-framework, datetime

```
1   <?php
2   // get number weeks of year for 2008
3   // result 52
4   echo date("W", mktime(0,0,0,12,28,2008));
5   ?>
```

How can i get the above result , using zend functions .also how can i get hte current year using zend

Comment: Isn't there always 52 weeks in a year? Why would you want to compute it?

Comment: 365 days is 52 weeks, 1 day. Leap years are 52 weeks, 2 days. If you decide that a week starts on a Monday, there can be 53 Mondays in a year, and therefore that year is considered to have 53 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->setDay(31)->setMonth(12);
echo $date->toString("w");
?>
```